# Is there a way to send scheduled message to azure service bus using spring cloud stream and get its sequence number

Tags: spring, stream, cloud

I am not able to find a way

Most of methods in spring cloud stream send method return Boolean
I used

```
 streamBridge.send("supply-out-0", MessageBuilder.withPayload(buildRequest())
                    .setHeader("x-delay",60000)//
               .setHeader(ServiceBusMessageHeaders.MESSAGE_ID,"12398_12345")//
                    .build(), MimeType.valueOf(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
```

I am not able to find any documentation which tells us how to access the sequence number of scheduled message